# Power BI: Row level security using SSAS Cube as data source

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas

Is possible to make Row Level Security on reports that are hosted in Power BI Report Server doing Live Connection to a SSAS Cube?

I want to provide embeded reports to a page ( using Iframe ), and these reports are hosted in Power BI Report Server and make Live Connection to SSAS multidimensional cube. In this scenario, is possible to do Row level security in my Power BI Report?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have Row Level Security on your SSAS MD cube at the moment?

Comment: Jonee, I don't have, because I read that only SSAS tabular can have Row Level Security

Comment: You can add a security model to SSAS MD to allow the same as RLS. Not sure if it works with Power BI, you would have to test it. Teo Lachev book https://prologika.com/applied-microsoft-analysis-services-2005/ has a good outline to implement a security model in Multi Dimensional